# Is there a way to reverse look up element's XPath usig selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

This many sound stupid, but I need to know an element's XPath after finding it via Selenium. The reason being that when I looked for that element, I used text search and thus, I do not know the exactly XPath, which I could use to fetch the aforementioned element's siblings. Even if it's not with Selenium, if there's a way to accomplish this indirectly via, say BeautifulSoup, then that'd be great.

The current output of my program is like this:

```
(Pdb) browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[contains(text(), "5StarMAX")]')

[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="8994add1f6f087a917bbb33f69f15f7c", element="7bad823c-1f3
e-445b-9a47-6d934fcacb8a")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="8994add1f6f087a917bbb33f69f1
5f7c", element="551df9b7-d2cb-4021-bb30-a2723c835adf")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="
8994add1f6f087a917bbb33f69f15f7c", element="b864c44b-8220-4010-843c-fbf0cfa1ba13")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webe
lement.WebElement (session="8994add1f6f087a917bbb33f69f15f7c", element="59d9f40d-d318-4e0d-9ab1-aa9df42d037c")>, <se
lenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="8994add1f6f087a917bbb33f69f15f7c", element="260795bd-e7c6-43
b1-a8f0-10b36eb69787")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="8994add1f6f087a917bbb33f69f15f7c
", element="4e46be00-4578-4741-adc9-a5b6fc67a3e9")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="8994
add1f6f087a917bbb33f69f15f7c", element="df66abcb-bd99-4670-af07-404c085afb28")>]
```

As you can see, I found the element, but I'd like to programmatically (using Python) search for its siblings. There's no way--at least that I know of (after trying to locate it using developer tool everywhere on the page)--to know the XPath of the element itself.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `BeautifulSoup` and `Selenium` together.

You may try [this solution](https://gist.github.com/ergoithz/6cf043e3fdedd1b94fcf#gistcomment-2682315) using [`xpath_soup()`](https://gist.github.com/ergoithz/6cf043e3fdedd1b94fcf#file-xpath_soup-py).

### Option-A

```py
import re
import itertools
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '<html><body><div><p>Hello World</p></div></body></html>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
elem = soup.find(string=re.compile('Hello World'))
xpath_soup(elem)
```

**output**

```
'/html/body/div/p'
```

### Option-B

Quoting `as-is`. You may have to change a few things here and there to make it work for you. [source](https://gist.github.com/ergoithz/6cf043e3fdedd1b94fcf#gistcomment-2682315)

```py
import re, itertools
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

def xpath_soup(element):
    components = []
    child = element if element.name else element.parent
    for parent in child.parents:
        siblings = parent.find_all(child.name, recursive=False)
        components.append(
            child.name
            if siblings == [child] else
            '%s[%d]' % (child.name, 1 + siblings.index(child))
            )
        child = parent
    components.reverse()
    return '/%s' % '/'.join(components)

def main():
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='phantomjs.exe')
    driver.set_window_size(1400,1000)
    driver.get("https://www.pinterest.com/search/pins/?q=old")

    buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//button[@data-test-id="seemoretoggle"]');
    for btn in buttons:
        btn.click()

    html = driver.page_source
    soup = BS(html, 'html.parser')
    elem = soup.find(string=re.compile('Tiny House interior'))
    print(elem)
    xpath_soup(elem)
    print(xpath_soup(elem))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

### Check these out as well:

1. https://qxf2.com/blog/auto-generate-xpaths-using-python/
2. https://gist.github.com/ergoithz/6cf043e3fdedd1b94fcf

Comment: Thank you. This is very cool! I will use this approach in desperate times. For now, I also found that using `following-sibling` in XPaths might do the trick at least for my need to iterate through siblings (I've asked a question about that here if you are willing to check out: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57862253/1330974). Will accept your answer above if nobody proposes better in the next couple of days. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the XPath of the parent element once you've found it. You can chain `.find_element_*()` calls. For example, the code below will find the element that contains the text "5StarMAX" and then the second find call finds the child DIV of the first element.

Note that the second XPath starts with a `.`. This means to start the search at the first element, `element`.

```
element = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(text(), "5StarMAX")]')
element.find_element_by_xpath('./div')
```

If it helps... using a single XPath to represent combining both finds would look like

```
//*[contains(text(), "5StarMAX")]/div
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I learned from you that `'./div'` allows one to narrow the scope of the search from the parent element being called. Having said that, I'm looking more for siblings of the tag that holds `'5StarMax'` and I believe (correct me if I'm wrong) what you suggested only allows me to dig deeper **below** (not **parallel to**) the tag that holds `'5StarMax'`. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: With XPath you can go up, down, or sideways through the DOM starting with the element that you are searching from. Take a look at some [XPath documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath), particularly Axes. You can use `following-sibling` and `preceding-sibling` to find siblings of the element you have. If you post some HTML and point out the element that you found and then the sibling element that you want to find based on the found element, we can work out the XPath needed.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was able to use `following-sibling` to get the elements I need. That is a very useful tip and thanks again! :)